# One's own, Oneself and himself

Tags: pronouns, reflexive-pronouns, parallelism

Here are two sentences with one's health and his health :

> One should take care of one's health.
>
> One should take care of his health.

Do the meaning differs if we add **own** in these sentences as follows :

> One should take care of one's own health.
>
> One should take care of his own health.

Next,

Here is a sentence with **oneself** and **one's** :

> One needs to provide food for onself and one's family.

Can I use use **himself** and **his** in the place of **oneself** and **one's** as :

> One needs to provide food for himself and his family.

It seems the gender bias pronoun **Himself** and **his** exclude women even If I have used them to refer to both man and woman.

Comment: No and yes, respectively. But it's not clear why you're asking this.

Comment: One is not a substitute for his/her, him/herself and should not be mixed.

Comment: Use the singular _their_ and Bob's your uncle. Thus: _"One should take care of **their** health."_ This is ooooold news.

Comment: @Robusto I'm asking because I'm confused wheather can I mix **himself** and **his** in the place of **oneself** and **one's** in written and spoken English. But **himself, his, his own** seem to be refering to only male even if I use them to refer to both man and woman. Thus, The ambiguity lies here.

Comment: Of course the masculine pronouns _himself_ and _his_ exclude females, just as _herself_ and _her_ exclude males! You can use _her_ in place of _one's_ just as easily as _his,_ so there's nothing intrinsically "male" about _one_ as a pronoun. The solution is the singular and gender-neutral _their, they, and them._ English lacks a gender-neutral singular pronoun; _one_ ain't it. This has been hashed over for decades. See [**this answer**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32714/37009) for some insight. In written and spoken English, that's how we solve the problem.

Comment: @yubrajsharma: I wouldn't advise it. It's long since become an antiquated artifact of the language.

Comment: True @Robusto . There aren't many contexts in which _one_ (as the _impersonal_ pronoun, mind, not in its rôle as a "prop-word") will not sound stilted or overly formal to our ear. The OP may benefit from the [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)) article.

Comment: There's also another issue involved with the use of **one**, If he/himself is masculin pronoun, **Their** and **Themselves** can be an option to use I think. For example: One needs to provide food for themselves and their family. ( can't I use **they, themselves and their** as neutral pronoun ?)

Comment: There's also the matter of question tags: "She needs a car, doesn't she?" is fine, but "One needs a car, doesn't one?" is almost laughable.

Answer (score 2):

1. One should take care of one's health.
2. One should take care of one's own health.
3. One should take care of his health.
4. One should take care of his own health.
5. One should feed oneself and one's family.

All the sentences are grammatical.

The sentences #1, 2 and 5 are formal, whereas 3 & 4 are normally used in spoken and informal English.

Besides, the pronoun you is considered counterpart of one in informal English.  So you can also say:

You should take care of your/your own health.

If you think the use of "his" in the sentence #3 is gender biased, you can use "their" instead of "his" in informal English as follows

One should take care of their health.

As for the use of own in the sentences #2 and 4, it puts emphasis on one's and his health.

Comment: I don't buy "not grammatically appropriate" regarding the pairing of ***one*** and ***his*** (it's relatively unusual, but I don't object to [*In order to become a conscious, individualised being, **one** needs **his** ego*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZO2gLSVJMb0C&pg=PA33&dq=%22one+needs+his%22+-%22no+one+needs%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22one%20needs%20his%22%20-%22no%20one%20needs%22&f=false)) And I *certainly* don't buy the idea that it's in any way more *grammatically* correct if you pair ***one*** with ***his or hers***. That's just misplaced "gender sensitivity".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I appreciate your comments.

Comment: I appreciate your *edit*. I can't find anything to disagree with now, so I've reversed my downvote!

Answer (score -1):

The first two versions don't have a different meaning, the word *"own"* is just an emphasis.
Now, the sentence

> One needs to provide food for himself and his family.

**should be avoided**. There are people, even linguists who think that's the way to handle a case where you can't or won't tell the gender but *"he"* does have a gender. Logically speaking a pronoun that serves the purpose to identify a specific gender is not fit to be used as neutral. The formal way is not to replace *"one"*, so only the

> One needs to provide food for oneself and one's family.

sentence is correct. Or you can convert the sentence to plural. And speaking of plural, we have **the singular they**:

> One needs to provide food for themself and their family.

A lot of people will jump at this sentence, first because they think *"themself"* is a non-existent word (my spell checker thinks it too) and second because they think the usage of *"they"* here is a pronoun-antecedent agreement error. Don't listen to them.
Whenever you need to use a personal pronoun but you can't or won't tell the gender, use *"they"*. It's certainly better than *"he"*, it won't make the sentence unnecessarily complex like *"he or she"* and of course *"he or she"* addresses only two genders so you still exclude those who don't identify with either of them—*"they"* on the other hand now serves as **the nonbinary (or gender neutral) pronoun**, too.
Of course in formal speech and text this is still frowned upon and teachers who teach English (especially those who teach it as a foreign language) will freak out because of this but still this is the pronoun you're looking for if you want to replace the pronoun *"one"* or in any other case you don't want to deal with genders. [Tom Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Scott_(entertainer)) sums it up well in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46ehrFk-gLk) and [here's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/singular-nonbinary-they) some further reading.

Comment: While I [agree](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/usage-of-they-them-their-in-place-of-he-him-his-or-she/62372#62372) with your conclusion, I strongly disagree with the arrogant prescriptivist reasoning used to arrive there. According to the first few paragraphs, all native English speakers were flatly in the wrong for hundreds of years when they used "he"/"him"/"his" as the neutral. That's absurd.

Comment: The neutral meaning of "he" (if ever really existed) doesn't exist anymore in English. Some do want to repopularize it but that won't change the fact that it is a male pronoun and the truly neutral "they", which comes from the singular they which exists for 700 years, already took over.

Edit: also you should look up the word arrogant, you're using it where it doesn't belong.

Comment: You could make the case that "he" *can no longer* be used for neutral references (or more sensibly, *should* no longer), but you can't make that case on the purely logical ground that it's a masculine pronoun, as that is arrogant prescriptivism that ignores actual usage for hundreds of years for the sake of arbitrary made-up rules. Unfortunately, the answer tries the latter and not the former.